# Dragging and Dropping Widgets of different Size in a DashBoard

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, angularjs-scope

I need to create a dashboard with different charts and grids which will be of different dimensions.

This is the sample, which is working -

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/h7ySb/7/]
```

The demerit is that all divs are of same size in the above example. My requirement is to create a dashboard with different dimensions, which can be swapped with each other by dragging and dropping, like for example :-

[http://datatorrent.github.io/malhar-dashboard-webapp/?utm_source=angularjs.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation#/]

Please suugest how to achieve this in jQuery and Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can try gridster for angular.
https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster 
Its dashboard example: 
https://rawgit.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster/master/index.html#/dashboard

Comment: Can you give a sample link to add this  angularJS configurations in a dot net project or MVC project?

Comment: AngularJs is a completely client side; works on basic html and javascript so you run it on any browser based application like how you would be using jquery or any other library.
If you are just interested for jquery and javasrcipt then you can directly go for the daddy here :  http://gridster.net